# Como ocultar ID en las rutas laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Tengo la siguiente URL: dominio.com/usuario/3/edit.

Quisiera saber si es recomendable que aparezca el ID del usuario en la URL, o seria mejor una URL como por ejemplo: dominio.com/usuario/edit.

En caso de ser mejor la ultima opción, como se podría hacer? modificando la Ruta Route::get a Route::post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es ocultar el id, puedes utilizar un slug para cada usuario, hay un paquete "slugify" que hace muy bien dicho trabajo y hace que las url se vean mejor, aparte de ocultar cuantos id puedes tener en tu tabla de la base de datos.

Si es por seguridad, que uses GET o POST no va a influir mucho.

En este caso el verbo más adecuado sigue siendo GET, pues no estás haciendo ninguna modificación a la base de datos, solo obteniendo datos de ella.

Por último, deberías aprovechar el model binding que ofrece laravel directamente en la ruta.

Comment: Ahí vi lo del model binding. Es altamente recomendable usar  model binding? o hay ciertas situaciones que se recomienda nomas?

Comment: Usar model binding te va a ahorrar tiempo, líneas de código y dolores de cabeza. Yo lo uso todas las veces que pueda, con slugs.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres cambiar la columna de la base de datos que se usa para el *Model Binding*,  digamos, por ejemplo, para un *token* o algún otro campo único, desde *Laravel 5.2*, puedes hacerlo añadiendo esto en tu modelo:

```
public function getRouteKeyName(){
    return 'token';
}
```

Respecto a usar *POST* en lugar de *GET*, es anti estándar (*RESTful*), *GET* es solo para obtener el o los recursos, y *POST* para crearlo o crearlos. Te recomiendo ver las buenas prácticas:

http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que deseas es que tu URL oculte o enmascare el id, te recomiendo usar Fakeids.

Hará que los ids sean enmascarados en tu URL, por ejemplo, en lugar de que te muestre tu url: 
-dominio.com/usuario/3/edit.

va a mostrarte algo como esto:
-dominio.com/usuario/192849273/edit.

Mucho más limpio tu URL que utilizando Encrypt y todo lo realiza de manera automática.

documentación: https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-FakeId